# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException on server

Tags: java, linux, terminal, centos, twilio

A small java program is throwing a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException` error when I try to call it from the CentOS 7 command line.  I read other postings about this error in android apps being caused by the need for the twilio client jars instead of the twilio sdk jars, but this is not android.  But this is a CentOS 7 server.  The same java program works when called from within a webapp in a tomcat installation on the same server, which has the same jar files in its lib folder as this small program has in its dependencies folder shown below.  **So why am I getting a `ClassNotFoundException` if the same jars are in the classpath?  How can I resolve these `ClassNotFoundException`s so that the small java program below can run properly?**

Here is what the terminal says is located in the root directory of the small program:

```
[user@domain bin]$ cd /home/user/javacode/
[user@domain javacode]$ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user   76 Aug 21 22:29 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 user user 4096 Aug 21 21:20 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user   24 Aug 21 22:32 bin
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user   87 Aug 22 02:36 dependencies
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 1313 Aug 21 19:28 SendText.java
```

Similarly, the `/bin` and `/mainpackage` folders contain the following:

```
[user@domain javacode]$ cd /home/user/javacode/bin
[user@domain bin]$ ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 24 Aug 21 22:32 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 76 Aug 21 22:29 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 27 Aug 21 22:32 mainpackage
[user@domain bin]$ cd /home/user/javacode/bin/mainpackage
[user@domain mainpackage]$ ls -al
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user   27 Aug 21 22:32 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 user user   24 Aug 21 22:32 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1495 Aug 21 22:32 SendText.class
```

I compile the program as follows:

```
[user@domain javacode]$ javac -d bin -cp .:/home/user/javacode/dependencies/twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5.jar:/home/user/javacode/dependencies/httpcore-4.1.2.jar SendText.java
```

Note that the two jars in the `javac` and `java` commands above are the only two relevant ones in the tomcat installation in which this code works,

But when I run the program from the `/bin` folder, it gives the following.  (Note that `xxxxxxxxxx` and `HelloThere` are `args` that go into `String[] args` in the main method.  `xxxxxxxxxx` is a valid cell phone number to receive a text, and `HelloThere` is the message.)

```
[user@domain mainpackage]$ cd /home/user/javacode/bin
[user@domain bin]$ java mainpackage.SendText xxxxxxxxxx HelloThere
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twilio/sdk/TwilioRestException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 6 more
```

I then double checked the list of jars in the dependencies folder and got the following (Note that I added extra jars below to rule out the possibility of missing jars, even though most of the below are not in the working tomcat installation):

```
[user@domain bin]$ cd /home/user/javacode/dependencies
[user@domain dependencies]$ ls -al
total 944
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user   4096 Aug 22 03:01 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user     76 Aug 21 22:29 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 433071 Aug 22 02:36 httpclient-4.2.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     40 Aug 22 02:36 httpclient-4.2.3.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   5911 Aug 22 02:36 httpclient-4.2.3.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     40 Aug 22 02:36 httpclient-4.2.3.pom.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 181200 Aug 21 21:24 httpcore-4.1.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     98 Aug 22 02:31 m2e-lastUpdated.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    193 Aug 22 02:36 _remote.repositories
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 165092 Aug 22 02:31 twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     40 Aug 22 02:31 twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   5113 Aug 22 02:31 twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     40 Aug 22 02:31 twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5.pom.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 129098 Aug 22 02:31 twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5-sources.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     40 Aug 22 02:31 twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5-sources.jar.sha1
```

For reference, the code of `SendText.java` is:

```
package mainpackage;

import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Message;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SendText {

  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "arealsid";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "arealtoken";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    String to = args[0];
    String body = args[1];
    // Build a filter for the MessageList
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", body));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", to));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+11234567654"));

    MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();
    Message message = messageFactory.create(params);
    System.out.println(message.getSid());
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the classpath?

Comment: @beny23 I added the `javac` and `java` command that reference the classpath to my OP.  Does this help?

Comment: Your question is now slightly inconsistent, inasmuch you've got one call to your program from the javacode directory with the classpath which shouldn't work because you're classes are in bin and one call when you are in the bin directory without the classpath.

Comment: @beny23 I fixed the discrepancy.  Have a look now.

Comment: You're not specifying the classpath when you run java?

Comment: @beny23 can you put the syntax you suggest in a comment and I will run it and report back?

Answer (score 1):

In order for Java to use your dependencies, you have to specify the classpath:

```
[user@domain mainpackage]$ cd /home/user/javacode/bin
[user@domain bin]$ java -cp .:"../dependencies/*" mainpackage.SendText xxxxxxxxxx HelloThere
```

Note, Java allows you to use wild cards to avoid having to specify each jar manually...

When you run your code via tomcat it automatically adds the jars in /lib to the classpath.

Comment: Your code results in a different `noClassDefFound` error, this time for `org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory`. I just re-read the OP, and it refers to `noClassDefFound` errors in the plural.  Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: You'll need commons-logging.jar in your dependencies directory. The reason why this doesn't occur in tomcat is most likely that tomcat has commons-logging in its lib folder...  Looking at the dependencies through the maven [twilio POM](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.twilio.sdk%7Ctwilio-java-sdk%7C3.4.6%7Cjar), it is likely that you're missing a few other jars. I know you're not using maven but it's a good way to find dependencies...

Comment: Thank you.  It is too late for me to continue this tonight. I will return to this tomorrow when I am awake.